# Is there a way to prove $\mathbf{\hat{Y}}^T\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{0}$ without resorting to summations?

Tags: regression, matrix, sum

I would like to show that $\mathbf{\hat{Y}}^T\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{0}$. I can solve this by saying that it is equivalent to showing $\sum e_i\hat{y}_i=0$. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to employ matrix methods to show that $\mathbf{\hat{Y}}^T\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{0}$. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some more context here? Are you taking about linear regression, with $\hat Y=X\hat\beta$?

Comment: @PedroSebe yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

$$\mathbf{e}=(I-P)\mathbf{y}$$

$$\mathbf{\hat{y}}=P\mathbf{y}$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\hat{y}}'\mathbf{e}&=\mathbf{y}'P'(I-P)\mathbf{y} \\
&=\mathbf{y}'(P'-P'P)\mathbf{y} \\
&=0
\end{align}

Last step uses the fact that $P$ is idempotent and symmetric.

Comment: This is perfect. I like the trick of using $\mathbf{\hat{y}}=P\mathbf{y}$!

Comment: It made sense when I first read your answer, but now I'm wondering: how do we know that $P$ is idempotent and symmetric?

Comment: @RonSnow: See the properties section of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) page.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!